# Let $F$ be the set of points of intersection of $E_{c}=0$ with $xy=c$ (for parameter c). Then find $F$ and $E_c$

Tags: geometry

> > Let $A=\{{xy=c \;|\; c\in \mathbb R-{0}}\}$. Let $E_{c}=0$ represent locus of point $P_{c}$ such that sum of slopes of normals drawn from it to $xy=c$  is equal to sum of ordinates of feet of normals. Let $F$ be the set of points of intersection of $E_{c}=0$ with $xy=c$ (for parameter c). Then find $F$ and $E_c$

**My Approach:**

Let any point on given hyperbola be $\bigg(\sqrt{c}t, \dfrac{\sqrt c}{t}\bigg)$ and let point $P_c$ be $(h,k)$.

Slope of normal to given hyperbola at $\bigg(\sqrt{c}t, \dfrac{\sqrt c}{t}\bigg)$ is $t^2$.

Equation of normal at $\bigg(\sqrt{c}t, \dfrac{\sqrt c}{t}\bigg)$ is $y-\dfrac{\sqrt {c}}{t}=t^2(x-\sqrt {c}t) \implies \sqrt {c}t^4-t^3x+ty-\sqrt{c}=0$. and this normal passes through $P_{c}$ so equation become $\sqrt{c}t^4-t^3h+tk-\sqrt{c}=0$

Now using Vieta's formula

$\sum t_1=\dfrac{h}{\sqrt c},\; \sum t_1t_2=0, \;\sum t_1t_2t_3=\dfrac{-k}{\sqrt c},\; \sum t_1t_2t_3t_4=-1$.

According to given condition of Question:

$t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2+t_4^2=\sqrt{c}\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt c}{t_1}+\dfrac{\sqrt c}{t_2}+\dfrac{\sqrt c}{t_3}+\dfrac{\sqrt c}{t_4}\bigg)$

After substituting values I am obtaining $E_c$ as $x^2=cy$.

But given answer for $E_c$ is $x^2=cy$ and for $F$ is $y^4-x^2=0$

I am not obtaining Curve $F$

Comment: This is the second post of yours in two days I've had to remove some inappropriate tags from. From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry." Please pay more attention to the tags you use in the future.

Comment: "I am not obtaining Curve F" I do not get $y^4-x^2=0$ either. What did you get?

Comment: Also, you cannot write $\bigg(\sqrt{c}t, \dfrac{\sqrt c}{t}\bigg)$ since $c$ can be negative.

Comment: @mathlove I'll edit that